# Array of structures within a structure?

Tags: c, struct, structure

I have a structure `Register` and a structure `ModbusReadStruct`. `Register` is declared as below:

```
typedef struct {
    int TypeID;
    char InstrumentType[32];
    char RegTag[32];
    char Protocol[32];
    int RegNum;
    char RW[32];
    char RegisterType[32];
    char Signed[32];
    char Inverted[32];
    char DataType[32];
    int Counts;
} Register;
```

I would like to declare the structure `ModbusReadStruct` as below:

```
typedef struct {
    int Address;
    int Port;
    int BaudRate;
    int DataBits;
    int StopBits;
    int RegID;
    int Sampling;
    char InstanceName[32];
    int InstNum;
    int MBNum;
    int PortNum;
    int RegNum;
    Register Register[64];
} ModbusReadStruct;
```

However this exact implementation leads to errors (Segmentation Fault). What would be the best way to achieve functionality similar to my idea above?

Comment: It's possible that the segmentation fault is in the code that uses it. I don't think there are any problems with the structs that you created.

Comment: There is no problem with having structures (or arrays of structures) within structures. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: The structures look fine, the crash is probably because of something else. Please use a debugger to catch the crash in action, so you can locate where it happens in your code.

Comment: Strange, the code worked before I added the array into the structure declaration. When i tried to debug it the debugger won't step or start at all. However When i removed that declaration the debugger worked fine.

Comment: Do note that the `ModbusReadSruct` has a size of `~15kB`, which may be too big to allocate on the stack.

Comment: @Mst137: post the code that shows the problem

Comment: I am not sure whether you can write same name Register for both variable instance and type. Please verfiy it too.

Comment: Problem solved, unsure what the problem itself was that caused the segmentation fault but one issue was the size of the structures I had created. With more reasonable array sizes I was able to debug at a reasonable speed.

Answer (score 1):

The structure declarations you posted are perfectly correct, except for your use of the same identifier `Register` for a type and for the name of the structure member of `ModbusReadStruct`.

The segmentation fault indicates a problem with your code, not with the structure declarations themselves.

As **EOF** commented, as declared, the `ModbusReadStruct` structure has a size of approximately 17KB.  While allocating such objects with automatic storage (aka *on the stack*) is possible on modern PCs, the stack space may be substantially less on embedded systems. Allocating a local array of `ModbusReadStruct` of sufficient size will also be a problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13379159)

Comment: @Jeeter: I beg to disagree: this answer does address the question, Mst137 never provided the offending code, but the problem seems to have been related to the structure size, as he was able to debug his problem by reducing the array sizes. I agree the question is poorly documented, but it suggest we keep the answer or delete the question.